# Normalize Phone Numbers Using Python

Tags: python

I am extremely new to python. I often get text files that have phone numbers is various formats. I am trying to create a python script that takes this text file and normalizes them into a format I can use.

I am trying to remove all symbols and spaces and just leave the numbers. As  well as add `+1` to the beginning and a comma (`,`) at the end.

```
import re

with open("test_numbers.txt") as file:
    dirty = file.read()
    clean = re.sub(r'[^0-9]', '', dirty)

print clean
```

I'm trying to use regex but it puts everything on a single line. Maybe I am going about this all wrong. I have not worked out a way to add the `+1` to the beginning of the number or add a comma at the end. Would appreciate any advice.

Comment: Your regex is probably deleting \n (and \r) - but applying the regex to the file is probably the wrong approach; it's better to read one line in at a time. Also, note that you may run into phone numbers that are already in international format - you may have to be careful.

Comment: You want to loop over your `dirty` variable. And inside the loop, you need to apply the regex to every line in the text file.

Answer (score 2):

This might help you:

```
import re

with open('test_numbers.txt') as f:
    dirty = f.readlines()

clean = []
for l in dirty:
    clean.apped('+1{},\n'.format(re.sub(r'[^0-9]', '', l)))
```

`clean` will be a list of lines with `+1` at the beginning and `,` at the end. You may then save it to a text file with:

```
with open('formatted_numbers.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.writelines(clean)
```

You can also use a one liner using list comprehension:

```
clean = ['+1{},\n'.format(re.sub(r'[^0-9]', '', l)) for l in dirty]
```