# phone regex space

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this phone regex, but I want it to accept spaces.

For example `+57 52 5252255` should pass, but currently it's not passing.
also "+91 9 820 09 8200" should pass
so a space anywhere is acceptable

```
var phone_regex =/^\s*(?:\+?(\d{1,3}))?[- (]*(\d{3})[- )]*(\d{3})[- ]*(\d{4})(?: *[x/#]{1}(\d+))?\s*$/;
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ofn9knay/268/

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50978414/normalize-phone-numbers-using-python

Comment: Just a thought, am sure someone will fix the regex for you but I would try strip away all the unnecessary symbols and spaces before validating the number. This way, you could define your own format for phone numbers before inserting it into your DB.

Answer (score 0):

In order to match that string, your second capturing group needs to accept 2 or 3 digits.

```js
pattern = /^\s*(?:\+?(\d{1,3}))?[- (]*(\d{2,3})[- )]*(\d{3})[- ]*(\d{4})(?: *[x/#]{1}(\d+))?\s*$/;

test_strings = [
    "+57 52 5252255",
    "9820098200#301",
    "+919820098200",
    "+91-982-009-8200",
    "+1 (866) 582-2655",
    "+91 444 741 4000",
];

for (var i = 0; i < test_strings.length; i++) {
  console.log(test_strings[i] + ": " + pattern.test(test_strings[i]));
}
```

Comment: i want the space to be anywhere not at certain places

Comment: The current regular expression does accept spaces between the number sets. Do you want a regular expression that will match an indefinitely repeated set of space/dash delimited series of numbers of arbitrary length? Can only the second set be surrounded by parentheses? Most importantly, do you have additional test strings?

Answer (score 0):

We could try to tweak your existing complicated regex, but assuming you already have the phone number as an input in a variable, then one simple thing to do would be to just remove all whitespace:

```js
var phone_regex =/^\s*(?:\+?(\d{1,3}))?[- (]*(\d{3})[- )]*(\d{3})[- ]*(\d{4})(?: *[x/#]{1}(\d+))?\s*$/;
var phone = "+91 9 820 09 8200";
phone = phone.replace(/ /g,'');
console.log(phone_regex.test(phone));
```

Then, just use your current regex as you were doing.

Comment: my current regex wont allow spaces as u can see in the fiddle

Comment: @Jamesmarcus Did you actually read my answer?  I'm suggesting to just strip whitespace from the number _before_ you apply your current regex.

Comment: oh i got it but currently this is my code https://jsfiddle.net/uekpasv6/ how can i tweak it to do what ur suggesting?

Comment: @Jamesmarcus Your demo is a bit thin, at least with regards to not being a real demo.  Just call `.replaece(/ /g, '')` on the phone number variable.

Comment: after doing this now the regex never matches !

Comment: Then your code has some problem.  The logic is working fine in the demo.